# 2GP: Dependent class is invalid and needs recompilation

Tags: second-generation-packaging

I am trying to create a `Managed` package version.

When I run the command:

```
sfdx force:package:version:create --package "My App" --postinstallscript AppInstallHandler.cls -w 10 --loglevel TRACE
```

I am getting lots of the same error:

> Dependent class is invalid and needs recompilation

But if I log into the scratch org and go to:

```
Setup > Apex Classes
```

And run the `Compile all classes` option, it works:

> Compilation Complete
> Compilation Successful

Also, if I go to:

```
Setup > Apex Test Execution
```

And run all the tests, they all pass successfully.

**sfdx-project.json**

```
{
    "packageDirectories": [
        {
            "path": "my-path",
            "default": true,
            "package": "My App",
            "versionName": "ver 0.1",
            "versionNumber": "0.1.0.NEXT"
        }
    ],
    "namespace": "my-namespace",
    "sfdcLoginUrl": "https://login.salesforce.com",
    "sourceApiVersion": "50.0",
    "packageAliases": {
        "My App": "0HoXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
    }
}
```

I am stuck. I am not clear where to look next to help uncover the root cause.

1. What might be causing the issue?
2. Where should I look next to help me investigate further?

Comment: Maybe you already tried this, but worth mentioning https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000340653&type=1&mode=1

Comment: Hi @AjFmO - I have compiled all my `Apex` and I don't have any `Triggers`. But honestly, I am not sure that article is relevant as I am using `2GP` so I believe it is based on my local files rather than the metadata in the scratch org.

Comment: Can you paste all the errors including overview of package contents? Can you list if any of your class depends on any other package? Also what does your sfdx-project.json look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got rid of the errors:

> Dependent class is invalid and needs recompilation

By adding `--definitionfile config/project-scratch-def.json` to the command:

```
sfdx force:package:version:create --package "My App" --postinstallscript AppInstallHandler.cls -w 10 --definitionfile config/project-scratch-def.json  --loglevel TRACE
```

Now I am getting a different error.